# Tabindex order on container element

Tags: html, accessibility

Let's say I have two columns (Left and Right). Each column contains links.
If I want the users to tab into the Right column links first would all the links in the Right column have to be `tabindex="0"` and all the links in the Left column have to be `tabindex="1"`?

Or can I have all links have `tabindex="0"` and then set `tabindex="0"` on the Right Column and `tabindex="1"` on the Left Column to have the user tab through the Right Column first?

I am not quite sure how nested tabbing works. 
I tried an example on http://jsfiddle.net/fhzjf4yg/ and I can't seem to understand how it traverses the tab index. If someone could explain how the ordering works that would help too!

Answer (score -5, accepted):

NOT CORRECT ANSWER, SORRY

You shouldn't have more than one tabindex="0" on a page, meaning that it should be unique. If i told you to go to tabindex="0" and there were two on the page, where would you go?

and there's no nesting you basicaly jump from 0 to 1 to 2 and so on

Comment: Could you explain in the jsfiddle why it jumps to the div container around the 'Google' link first even though that container has `tabindex="1"` ?

Comment: There's actually nothing in this entire answer which is correct, it's 100% wrong.

Comment: To give @ChaBukuBakkes response a bit more depth: `tabindex="0"` is a completely fine (and actually only viable) approach to tell the browser an element should be accessible via tabbing. Zero activates tab navigation on an element that wouldn't be (e.g. a container) and the browser will simply use the visual flow to put it into the correct position. Positive values overwrite the default tabbing flow and might not actually be what's desired.

Answer (score 8):

Look at how tabindex is explained here ([Using tabindex - Web fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/using-tabindex)). From the link:

> tabindex="0": Inserts an element into the natural tab order.
>
> tabindex="-1": Removes an element from the natural tab order, but the element can still be focused by calling its focus() method
>
> tabindex="5": Any tabindex greater than 0 jumps the element to the front of the natural tab order.

Most importantly:

> Using a tabindex greater than 0 is considered an anti-pattern.

Basically if you want to start with the second list you can assign the elements in it a tabindex of 1 and leave the rest of the elements without a tabindex and it will select in the order you are trying to do.

Example:

```
<div id="element1">First No tab index</div>
<div id="element2">Second No tab index</div>
<div id="element3" tabindex="1">Third: has tab index</div>
```

`<div id="element3" tabindex="1">` will be selected first when tabbing because it establishes a different order.

It would be exactly the same if you assigned them in this way:

```
<div id="element1" tabindex="0">First No tab index</div>
<div id="element2" tabindex="0">Second No tab index</div>
<div id="element3" tabindex="1">Third: has tab index</div>
```

It has been suggested in multiple places I've read that using tabindex greater than 0 is not really a good way to do it.

Edit: Another way to have a screen reader read as you are suggesting is to use CSS to rearrange the DOM order visually. You can have the markup in the order you want read and show it in a different order. With flexbox you can use `flex-direction: row-reverse` in your case or simply use `order: 1;` on the first box you want read and `order: 2;` on the second box.

Taking stuff out of the DOM order is not accessible because it creates a different experience completely for mouse-users vs keyboard users of all types.

Answer (score 3):

@molda's answer is marked as -2 (as of viewing it today) but is marked as the correct answer.  Not sure what's up with that but he has several wrong comments in his answer.

> You shouldn't have more than one tabindex="0" on a page

You can have as many `tabindex="0"` as you want.  It just inserts the element into the natural tab order.  However, you should only need it on elements that are not naturally in the tab order already (you don't need it on an <a>), and it should only be set on an element that will be interactive.  Setting it on a random <div> is bad.

> If i told you to go to tabindex="0" and there were two on the page, where would you go?

Focus would go to the next natural element in the tab sequence, which is controlled by the DOM.

> (from comment section) If there's more than one tabindex with same index it just cares about the first one and ignores the rest

That's just blatantly wrong.  All elements with the same positive tabindex will be grouped together and the order they receive focus will be the DOM order.  They will all be cycled through first, and then the next group of the next lowest (positive) tabindex will be cycled through.

@chabuku's answer is more accurate, with regards to the definition of `tabindex` and the anti-pattern warning when using tabindex > 0.  You will almost always break keyboard accessibility if you use tabindex > 0.  Don't do it.

If you have two columns of links and want your tabbing to go backwards, you really really need to think about the design of the page and how it affects user experience.  For LTR (left to right) languages, such as English and romance languages, the natural tab order should be from left to right, then top to bottom.  If you force it to the right column then left column, that can be very confusing.

For RTL languages (Arabic, Hebrew, Farsi, etc), the tabbing order is right to left.  The browser handles that automatically for you.  If you try to force a certain tabbing order, then you might break RTL language support.

If you really need the right column to receive focus first, then use CSS to move the right column to the right but have the right column **first** in the DOM.  Something like this:

```
<style>
  div {border: 1px black solid; display: inline;}
</style>

<!-- column on the right but receives focus first -->
<div style="float:right">
  <a href="blah">a</a>
  <a href="blah">b</a>
  <a href="blah">c</a>
</div>

<!-- column on the left but receives focus second -->
<div>
  <a href="blah">d</a>
  <a href="blah">e</a>
  <a href="blah">f</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Solid answer as well. +1 for more info on RTL languages, I wasn't even aware of that. It's not a new question though so the OP likely hasn't seen it yet. I found this question when searching and realized WOW this accepted answer is *WRONG*

Comment: agreed.  i don't usually comment on old questions but it was just so blatantly wrong that it was hard to not say something